# How do I modify an array while I am iterating over it in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

I'm just learning Ruby so apologies if this is too newbie for around here, but I can't work this out from the pickaxe book (probably just not reading carefully enough).
Anyway, if I have an array like so:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

...and I want to, say, multiply each value in the array by 3, I have worked out that doing the following:

```
arr.each {|item| item *= 3}
```

...will not get me what I want (and I understand why, I'm not modifying the array itself).

What I don't get is how to modify the original array from inside the code block after the iterator. I'm sure this is very easy.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Use `map` to create a new array from the old one:

```
arr2 = arr.map {|item| item * 3}
```

Use `map!` to modify the array in place:

```
arr.map! {|item| item * 3}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/SVhrK)

Comment: If you really need to modify each element, using map would definitely be more elegant, imho.

Comment: And if you want to modify the array itself use map! instead

Answer (score 21):

To directly modify the array, use `arr.map! {|item| item*3}`. To create a new array based on the original (which is often preferable), use `arr.map {|item| item*3}`. In fact, I always think twice before using `each`, because usually there's a higher-order function like `map`, `select` or `inject` that does what I want.

Comment: What if you don't want to do an enumerating operation? What if you just want to do something like `arr.map!{ destructive_op}` to permanently change `arr`?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander: I'm not sure what you mean. It might be worth asking as a real question with details and stuff.

Comment: I'll have to think about it. Other than very narrow element modification, what destructive operations on structures aren't enumerable?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander: I am still having a hard time understanding. If you can't look at a structure's contents, you can't transform its contents. It kind of sounds like you aren't interested in modifying a structure, and instead just want to assign a variable — but I might be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5):

```
arr.collect! {|item| item * 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already mentioned that array.map is the more elegant solution here, but you can simply add a "!" to the end of array.each and you can still modify the array. Adding "!" to the end of #map, #each, #collect, etc. will modify the existing array.

Comment: Tried this, but for both `each!` and `each_with_index!` I get an undefined method error

Comment: This is wrong, as there's no built-in method in Ruby's like each! and/or each_with_index!. I'd recommend to double check your answer, Andrew. This applies to some methods only (map!, compact!, collect!, reject!, etc).